# Add a dynamic (user generated) string to a listbox at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

How can I use the Listbox control (or any other control) to allow the user to add custom strings to the control **at runtime**? I want this to be one control, I don't want to have to add the string manually in the code behind by adding a listbox item. I'd also like the items to be editable in place.

In Delphi, they have the Memo component, which allows the user to add lines of text. The runtime then converts this additional text to a string object.

Is something similar possible in C#?

Comment: Question is not clear, why exactly do you mean by "after compiling" ? Also why do you mentionig TMemo control ? In Winforms eqivalent of Delphi's TMemo is multiline TextBox.

Comment: i want the ability to have the user create new strings, not me.
the listbox dosen't let you edit itself or add lines after running it.

i mentioned it because the multiline only let you edit 1 string(the textbox.text string), i want to be able to add as many indavidual strings as i want

Answer (score 1):

Collection based controls usually have the property called "Items". This property is a collection of objects with will be shown. You can simply use:

```
ListBox.Items.Add(yourStringVariable)
```

If you want to add complex object, then override .ToString method to return a name for that instance of your object. ListBox internally calls .ToString on the object instance to render the text.

Comment: i want the ability to have the user create new strings, not me. the listbox dosen't let you edit itself or add lines after running it

Comment: ListBox will render whatever your object's .ToString is returning (in a string's case, its the string itself). ListBox is not for editing, rather displaying. You will have to use another control to edit the text or object instance.

Comment: that is exactly my question.
i don't want to use another textbox by the side of it and adding objects to the list from backstage, i want the user to be able to edit it's own list. the use of another textbox slows the whole procedure and doesn't sit well with a simple UI

Comment: Are you looking for a [ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx)? A dropdown where user can edit the text?

Comment: something like that, except i want a list and not a dropdown, and you can't add new objects to the combo box while running the application

Answer (score 1):

You might look into the **Data grid view**.

It behaves a lot like a listbox, but users can edit the cells. I believe it can be configured to let users add a new (empty) row, if not, a simple button could easily accomplish this.

Once the new row has been added, the user can edit its contents as much as they want.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0ywh3cz.aspx

Answer (score 0):

just add your String to Items in this way

```
//user fill the   textBox1
//for given ListBox listbox
listbox.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: i want the ability to have the user create new strings, not me.
the listbox dosen't let you edit itself or add lines after running it

Comment: :-o, "new Item Text" is a string  and you can place each string you want, like your textBox.Text.

Comment: that is exactly what i'm trying to avoide. i don't want to use another textbox by the side of it and adding objects to the list from backstage, i want the user to be able to edit it's own list. the use of another textbox slows the whole procedure and doesn't sit well with a simple UI